# PowerBI Dax datetime - Filter on year transition does not work

Tags: datetime, filter, powerbi, dax

I use a gauge in `PowerBI` to show if a value is over or under the average of the last 2 Tuesday(for instance).
The *target value* of the Gauge is a measure:

```
AverageLastdays = 
CALCULATE (
        AVERAGE(Data1[TTSTotal]);
        FILTER( Data1; 
                   Data1[Date] = (Data1[CurrDate]-8) --Tuesday last Week
                || Data1[Date] = (Data1[CurrDate]-15) --Tuesday 2 Weeks ago
            )
    )
```

where 
`CurrDate = TODAY()`

and the Date column is populated with proper dates from `sept2017 to Jan2018.`

As soon as the date reach 2017 (if I use -18 for instance) this date is not considered in the filter.

I used a Card to visualize the date which seems correct.

I'd like to calculate the average of the last 6 weeks but I can only do 2 weeks for the moments because 2017 was 2 weeks ago.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going on with your formula, I suspect it's because your Integers (e.g. -8) are implicitly converted to datetime.

Anyway I imagine you could solve this another way using the DATEDIFF function, something like:

```
...
DATEDIFF ( Data1[Date] , Data1[CurrDate] , DAY ) = 8 --Tuesday last Week
...
```